# Force.com IDE Plugin doesn't load in Eclipse Luna

Tags: force.com, ide, java, eclipse, force.com-ide

I did a new clean Mac OS Yosemite Installation and want to install the Force.com IDE.

First I installed the [Java SE Development Kit 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), then I installed the newest version of the [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 32 Bit](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).
Afterwards I installed the [Force.com IDE Plugin](http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42).

If I open Eclipse now, I can't open the *Force.com IDE Perspective* and I can't create a new *Force.com Project* ?

Answer (score 1):

Are both Java 8 JDK and Eclipse Luna 32bit?

In the "About Eclipse" screen, which Java version is running?

Why did you choose 32bit?

I installed 64bit Java 8 JRE, Eclipse Luna and Force.com IDE plugin on my laptop last week. It runs without issues.

Comment: Peter I had that issue as I mistaking downloaded 64 bit jdk and the 32 bit eclipse.  Felt pretty dumb when I figured it out,  but it definately had me confused for awhile.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [requirements](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation), they only support Java 7 and eclipse 4.2 (Juno) and 4.3 (Kepler). I too have Java 8, but I installed Kepler (Luna wasn't out yet) and it seems to work somewhat ok.

The release version of the plugin itself (v31) is a couple versions behind force.com (v33). Maybe the next release will include support for Luna.

Comment: Before the clean Yosemite Installation my Eclipse Luna works fine with the newest Force.com Plugin.